# Multiple classes in Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, object

I am learning OOPS in Python. I encountered this piece of code during my course.

```
class Point(object):
def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.x=x
    self.y=y


class Line(object):        
def __init__(self,p1,p2):
    self.p1=p1
    self.p2=p2

def slope(self):
    return (self.p2.y - self.p1.y)/         (self.p2.x-self.p1.x)
```

Let's say for Point class I have two instances P1(11,6) and P2(12,3). For class Line, I have one object L1(7,2). What does it mean that self.p2.y? What value would be accessed here?

I have looked at many places but couldn't find this concept?

Comment: It's assuming `p1` and `p2` are instances of your `Point` class, not integers. Rather than `L1(7,2)`, you should use `L1(P1, P2)` in your example.

Answer (score 1):

self refers to the object of that class. the variables after the `.` operator are attributes

you can use something other than self, but its good practice to use self.

so for P1, self refers to the P1 object.

theres also a version of self for classes (cls) but thats for class methods

Comment: @itsrxmmy...But what is the value being accessed.?

Comment: since self is the object, whatever follows is an attribute.  so for \_\_init\_\_ of the Line class, self.p1 refers to the p1 attribute

Comment: I read the question wrong. (in the slope function) ```self``` refers to the object, ```p2``` refers to the attribute of that object, and ```y``` is the attribute of the ```p2``` attribute. its nested pretty much.